# SOAP: how to analyse WSDL and XSD files?

Tags: web-services, soap, xsd, wsdl

I am very new to SOAP, and I need to call some webservices written in SOAP 1.1

The webservice provider gave me a zip file, with two directories:

- one with WSDL files
- one with XSD files

They are very difficult to read, as they are structured in XML, and they link to each other. Very confusing.

Can you recommend some tools that can easily provide a full list of webservices and their parameters, without having to read through the XML and open multiple files?

Answer (score 1):

I found this open source software called SoapUI:
https://www.soapui.org

you can add WSDL files, and it maps all the webservices defined there, with all the parameters

it automatically builds the request XML, and also allows you to make calls

Answer (score 0):

You can import wsdl and xsd files from you IDE like Eclipse. It comes with features that permit you explore each part of those documents.

[here](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.wst.wsdl.ui.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftimpwsdl.html) you can find the steps to import wsdl.

If you want a paid tool , I recommend you get 
[oxygenxml](https://www.oxygenxml.com/xml_editor/wsdl_editor.html) . It provides a editor for wsdl. You can download the trial version and prove it.